# How do I insert a date value into a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: php, postgresql

How to insert date in PostgreSQL? This seems to be wrong:

```
public function insert( $name, $author ) {
    $this->query = "INSERT INTO people ( name, author, date )
    VALUES ( '$name', '$author', to_timestamp('2/3/2016 12:05')";

    return $result = pg_query( $this->connection, $this->query );
}

$database->insert( 'someName', 'SomeAuthor' );
```

Comment: What is wrong is that you are not using parameters to pass in, well, parameters.  And you are using a non-standard format for a date/time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'2016-03-02 12:05:00' is one way...

```
$this->query = "INSERT INTO people ( name, author, date )
    VALUES ( '$name', '$author', '2016-03-02 12:05:00')";
```